# Django Session Scope issue between different apps within a project

Tags: django, django-sessions

I am following a tutorial about Creating Shopping Cart this here [link](https://academy.muva.tech/blog/creating-shopping-cart-views-shop-products-django-2-0-python-3-6/).

I wanted to make some tweaks on my own, I tried to add a cart icon in the navbar capable of displaying no. of items and total of the items in the cart.

But this icon shows values correctly only when I am on cart's template page, on rest of the pages it is blank. (To me it seems to be problem with the scope of sessions).

Project Structure image - (https://academy.muva.tech/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cart.png)

image of cart icon on cart detail page-(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUHOj.jpg)

image of cart icon on other page-(https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5qTa.jpg)

**base.html**

```
<div class="shopping-item">
    <a href="{% url 'cart:cart_detail'%}">Cart - <span class="cart-amunt">{% with totail_items=cart|length %}Rs {{ cart.get_total_price }}</span> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="product-count">{% if cart|length > 0 %}{{ cart.cart_item_count }}{% else %}0{% endif %}{% endwith %}</span></a>
</div>
```

**detail.html**( cart page )

```
{% extends 'shop/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
    Your Shopping Cart
{% endblock %}



{% block body_block %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 6%">
        <h2>Your Shopping Cart<br><br>
            <span class="badge pull-right">
                {% with totail_items=cart|length %}
                    {% if cart|length > 0 %}
                        My Shopping Order:
                        <a href="{% url "cart:cart_detail" %}" style="color: #ffffff">
                            {{ cart.cart_item_count }} item {{ totail_items|pluralize }}, Rs. {{ cart.get_total_price }}
                        </a>
                        {% else %}
                        Your cart is empty.
                    {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
            </span>
        </h2>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead style="background-color: #5AC8FA">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Remove</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for item in cart %}
                    {% with product=item.product  %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{ product.get__absolute_url }}">
                                    <img src="{% if product.image %} {{ product.image.url }} {% else %} {% static 'img/default.jpg' %} {% endif %}" alt="..." style="height: 130px; width: auto">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <form action="{% url "cart:cart_add" product.id %}" method="post">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
                                    {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
                                    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-info">
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{% url "cart:cart_remove" product.id %}">Remove</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>Rs. {{ item.price }}</td>
                            <td>Rs. {{ item.total_price }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endwith %}
                {% endfor %}
                <tr style="background-color: #5AC8FA">
                    <td><b>Total</b></td>
                    <td colspan="4"></td>
                    <td colspan="num"><b>Rs. {{ cart.get_total_price }}</b></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <p class="text-right">
            <a href="{% url "shop:product_list" %}" class="btn btn-default">Continue Shopping</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Checkout</a>
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**cart.py**(inside the app "*cart* ")

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from shop.models import Product



class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0, 'price':str(product.price)}
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in self.cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def cart_item_count(self):
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.session.modified = True
```

**views.py**(of "cart")

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from shop.models import Product
from .cart import Cart
from .forms import CartAddProductForm



def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'], 'update': True})
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

**urls.py**( of "cart")

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'cart'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    url(r'^add/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
    url(r'^remove/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
]
```

**urls.py**( of "project")

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from user_auth import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^user_auth/', include('user_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^special/$', views.special, name = 'special'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name = 'logout'),
    url(r'^auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    path('cart', include('cart.urls')),
    url(r'^shop/', include('shop.urls')),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Thanks